# Is there a way to clearly show the current TFS branch from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are moving to a process where multiple developers will be working on solutions in a couple of different TFS branches. Already there has been confusion where people open solutions from a branch different to what they intend. The MRU list in VS 2010 only shows the solution name, not branch name. It's also not clear once the solution is open unless people check **Properties** or mouse over the current tab.

Is there a VS option or extension where the current TFS branch is prominently shown in some way? Or even a solution based on what folders the solution has been opened from on the file system?

Comment: I find it useful to rename the .sln files when I check out a branch and add a tag to the name indicating which branch it's from.  It's not particularly "clean," but it's easy.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is a very simple VS extension titled *[Customize Visual Studio Window Title](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle)*. Once installed it will show the solution name plus the parent folder in the VS windows title bar instead of just the solution name.

For example:

> ***TotallyAwesomeSolution*** becomes ***NewFeatureA\TotallyAwesomeSolution***

Comment: The current version allows to configure the min and max depth distance from the solution file, not only the parent folder. This is great because only with the parent folder, in many cases, it's not enough to differentiate the branches.

Comment: And you can also add special tags, like [workspaceName]

Comment: Specifically, you want to set "farthest parent folder depth" to a large number (something like 99 should work).

Comment: For VS2013 - https://github.com/mayerwin/vs-customize-window-title/releases/tag/3.8.1

Comment: To make it work with VS2019 follow this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636350/re-enable-title-bar-in-visual-studio-2019/54600661)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to see it. What I have done in the past is to create a workspace per branch. Then in the Source Control Explorer and the Pending Changes window you see the currently selected workspace and thus the active branch.

Comment: That's a way to see the active branch (=workspace) in Source Control Explorer and Pending Changes only. What branch the files in Solution Explorer belongs to is something different.

Comment: You can use the VS Commands extension for this purpose: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece