# How to differentiate branches in VS using tfs?

Tags: tfs, branch

I got 3 branches, dev, release, and another branch for another team.

If I have multiple VS open it's difficult to tell which branch I'm working on. Since the project names are the same.

For now I right click on branch and open in explorer then I can tell due to path.

Advise?

Thanks

Rick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to clearly show the current TFS branch from Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313452/is-there-a-way-to-clearly-show-the-current-tfs-branch-from-visual-studio)

Comment: In all my searching this did not come up.

Thanks, that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the only way to tell which branch your Solution was loaded from. You may find it easyer if you have a separate workspace for each branch. That way you:

1. Need only look at the workspace name
2. Will not accidentally check in the wrong thing to the wrong branch