# Visual Studio Code [Unsupported] not resolved

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-web-developer

Even after uninstalling and reinstalling I am facing the issue of Unsupported in Visual Studio Code title bar.  Can anybody help me with the issue?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error so that we can help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636350/re-enable-title-bar-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: I can tell you the message that is popping @Vishnu "Your code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall"

Comment: @wiretext this is not my problem's solution.

Comment: I resolved this issue recently by deleting the earlier instance of my VS Code and reinstalling again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might get this after installing some extensions that directly modify (patch) the VS Code product.

I got this issue after installing "SynthWave 84" extension.

[Official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported) is recommending the reinstallation of VSCode!

However, Took the following steps to resolve this issue as I never wanted to reinstall VSCode!

- Uninstall "SynthWave 84" extension and this restarts VSCode
- Restart VSCode manually again by closing all the VSCode projects
- Update VSCode (Click on Settings -> Check for Updates) and this restarts VSCode.

Voila, the issue got resolved without having to reinstall VSCode.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I have already resolved my error.

Answer (score 14):

1. Install the extension "Fix VSCode Checksums"
2. Open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and then write and select "Fix Checksums: Apply"
3. Finally, close VS Code and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue as of now by uninstalling and reinstalling after removing the patch extension I used.
Now my VS Code is working amazingly

Comment: This worked, and it may be useful for others to know that VS Code saved all my settings, repositories, recent files, even the tabs I had open! So it is a very low risk option.

Answer (score 1):

1: Install the extension "Fix VSCode Checksums"
2: Open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and then write
and select "Fix Checksums: Apply"
3: Finally, close VS Code and open it again.

MY PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: This exact solution is already mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68449626/17175441